Connecting symfony to docker mysql
I am getting this error:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for db failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

My docker-compose is like follows:
 services:
          db:
            image: mysql:latest
            container_name: db
            environment:
              MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: weply
              MYSQL_DATABASE: weply
              MYSQL_USER: weply
              MYSQL_PASSWORD: weply
            ports:
              - "6033:3306"
            volumes:
              - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
          phpmyadmin:
            image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
            container_name: pma
            platform: linux/amd64
            links:
              - db
            environment:
              PMA_HOST: db
              PMA_PORT: 3306
              PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
            restart: always
            ports:
              - 8081:80
        
        ###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
 volumes:
     dbdata:

And my .env DATABASE_URL
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:weply@db:3306/weply"

I can connect through browse ( the phpmyadmin container :8080 ). But when I try to create new migration this happens. Not sure where should I set this servname/nodename.

"when I try to create new migration" -- please be precise, what are you doing? What is the output you receive? Ensure you stripped all irrelevant dependencies to get a [mcve], too!

@UlrichEckhardt Its a new installation of symfony 7. What i am executing is php bin/console make:migration after simple model is created. E.g. User model with email and password fields. Literally nothing more.

To reproduce it, you can simply make one model, add the docker-compose code and run docker-compose up -d. Try to create migration afterwards php bin/console make:migration

Well, if it's so simple, why not [edit] your question to include the details?
